# How powerful is Daisy Johnson/Quake at the end of Season 5?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

It's implied throughout the later seasons of Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. that Daisy Johnson is one of the more powerful beings on Earth (certainly within the show, although we don't have any obvious points of comparison with the wider MCU) as a normal Inhuman. During the season finale, whilst fighting Talbot/Graviton, she is outclassed until she

> injects herself with the Centipede serum that Fitz-Simmons have blended with Jiaying's healing DNA

after which she is able to beat Talbot/Graviton.

We know from Season 1 that Centipede serum grants enhanced strength and some regenerative ability itself (from the Extremis components) to normal humans, and from Daniel Whitehall in Season 2 that Jiaying's healing ability can be 'grafted' onto a human (via some rather highly unethical surgical procedures). However, what effects would these elements have on an Inhuman like Daisy?

We see that her powers increase, but is she now also physically stronger? And does she now have any of her mother's, or generic Centipede/Extremis, regenerative abilities?

Comment: She actually has physical powers to begin with (or maybe she can use her vibration powers for that purpose). This was probably most obvious recently, when she brawled with Talbot and took falls that left craters, tore up pavement, and more (before taking the serum); but it's also been evident in occasional discussions of her higher metabolic rate, her talent for hand-to-hand combat despite having about 30 years less experience than May, and so forth. The issue with Daisy has always been (since she *was* Daisy, and not Skye) to prevent her from outclassing the rest of the team.

Comment: Given that (when pressed) she can cause avalanches, tear apart superhuman robots, and survive 2000 foot falls with a few injuries, they've had to employ a variety of reasons, some more plausible than others.